# Label several email addresses in Gmail in one go

Tags: gmail, gmail-contacts, gmail-labels

How do I put a contact group label on several email address in bulk instead of putting a label in every email address one at a time.

For example: I have 100 email address and I want to create a contact group called "holidays 2011". I don't want to enter every email through the process of push "new contact" and write the email address" and push "groups" and looking for the label called "holidays 2011" between hundreds of labels and push "holidays 2011".

If I spend 7 seconds to complete the entire process for one contact, that means for 100 email address I am going to spend 700 seconds. Besides, to do it that way is very boring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have created the contact group, you can add multiple email addresses or contacts at one time.  To add email addresses, select the group on the left (which lists current members.  Then click the *Add to "groupname"* button which will open a text box.  Type in or paste in the addresses, separated by commas, and then click *Add*.

To add existing contacts to a group, you can click the check-box by those you want, and then select the group name from the *Groups* drop-down list.